# Binding losing it's binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl

My Bindings start out working and then drop when I interact with the control.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Width="100" Background="Cyan"
                 Text="{Binding Path=DP_in_UserControl,
                                FallbackValue='Fallback',
                                TargetNullValue='TargetNull',
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Label Width="100" Background="Magenta"
               Content="{Binding Path=DP_in_UserControl,
                                 FallbackValue='Fallback',
                                 TargetNullValue='TargetNull'}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string DP_in_UserControl
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DP_in_UserControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DP_in_UserControlProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DP_in_UserControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DP_in_UserControl", typeof(string),
            typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata("UC Default"));

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I have a MainWindow:

```
<StackPanel Margin="25">
    <local:MyUserControl VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         DP_in_UserControl="{Binding DP_in_MainWindow}"/>
    <Label Background="Yellow"
           Content="{Binding DP_in_MainWindow,
                             FallbackValue='Fallback',
                             TargetNullValue='TargetNull'}"/>
    <Button Content="Change DP__in__MainWindow"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string DP_in_MainWindow
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DP_in_MainWindowProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DP_in_MainWindowProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DP_in_MainWindowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DP_in_MainWindow", typeof(string),
            typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("MW Default"));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
        DP_in_MainWindow = "Changed";
}
```

The window generated starts as:

[image: Startup state]

If I type in the TextBox on the UserControl (cyan), only the UserControl's Label (magenta) updates:

[image: I typed]

If I then click the Button which changes DP_in_MainWindow, only the Label defined in MainWindow (yellow) updates.

[image: ButtonClick After Typing]

BUT if I re-launch it and *first* click the button, all three update correctly:

[image: ButtonClick first]

And then typing again breaks the Bindings and only updates the Control's Label:

[image: Binding broken again]

What is going on here and how to I make the bindings maintain their bound-ness the XAML way. I know I could hack it together in the C# and that's most of the answers I'm seeing but there has to be a simple 'correct' way to do it.

I've experimented with all sorts of combinations of ControlTemplates and alternate bindings by name and ... just haven't hit the right combination.

Comment: Have you tried by specifying the `Mode` as `TwoWay`?

Comment: @dhilmathy I did but I don't remember what combination of other mess I had at that time. I'll set them all TwoWay right now and report back.

Comment: @dhilmathy I *know* I'd already tried it but that was the problem. The offending binding was `<local:MyUserControl DP_in_UserControl="{Binding DP_in_MainWindow}"/>`  Put that as an answer and I'll mash the accept button.

Comment: Someone is going to shamelessly steal my pretty example for a blog and I'm sure folks will read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be with the [`Binding.Mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.mode?view=netframework-4.7.2). Try setting `TwoWay` binding at your `UserControl` binding.

```
<local:MyUserControl VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     DP_in_UserControl="{Binding DP_in_MainWindow, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```